# v-if not updating nav bar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, header, render

I'm building an application using VUE JS in which there is a header component. In this component, I'm conditionally showing sub-header based on routes. So, v-if is not rendering the sub-header once the data-property is updated.

```
    <nav v-if="module === 'ap'" id="account-nav">
    </nav>
    <nav v-if="module === 'ip'" id="account-nav">
    </nav>

watch: {
    '$route' (to) {
        if(to.path.includes('/ap/')) {
            this.module = 'ap'
        } else if (to.path.includes('/ip/')) {
            this.module = 'ip'
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: you're missing  closing `"` in `v-if="module === 'ip'`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim It is there I just missed to add it here

Comment: please log the `to` param and give me the output `'$route' (to) { console.log(to) ...`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim screenshot of console added

Comment: why both ids of nav are the same

Comment: @tuhin47 because they only render based on condition and only one is true at a time.